# How can I configure email accounts in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: email-client

How can I configure email accounts such as Gmail, yahoo etc in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: How to configure where, and with what? All services mentioned work primarily via web. They can also be used with a local email client. You need to [edit] ans post what you really want to do (and in what way it relates to Ubuntu because all the settings are the same no matter where youŕe using the services from and, if using the same client like Thunderbird, configuration is exactly the same as in any other OS the same software runs in).

Answer (score 3):

In order to configure your mail account from Ubuntu you need to install a mail client in Ubuntu.

According to me Thunderbird is the best available option to you to access mail from Ubuntu. Assuming that you know you can access your mail through webmail(Via browser).

Check if `thunderbird` is already installed or not. If not, install it by opening a `terminal` and running the following command.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install thunderbird
```

Once installed you can run the thunderbird application and start configuring your mail id in thunderbird.

If you feel uncomfortable with `terminal and commands`, you can install thunderbird from software center.

Navigate to **Software center > search "thunderbird" >> click on install button >> provide password** and wait installation to be completed.

*Please note you may need to disable **secure apps** in your mail settings to use it with mail clients.*

Answer (score 1):

Download [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/). It is the best email client which I used on Ubuntu.

Have tried multiple clients like Nylas, Claw, Kmail etc. but they were not very reliable and user friendly.

Comment: You need to provide more detail Vinesh. The question was how to configure, your answer provides only 50% of an answer, you could elaborate by providing information on how to configure Gmail within the Thunderbird mail client.